# Does the search is impacted if SharePoint site collection administrator is an invalid account?

Tags: search

We have a SharePoint 2013 environment and search service application is configured properly. There are certain site collections where the site collection administrator is only "Account-x" and recently "Account-X" left the company so this account is removed from AD. So certain site collections now have the invalid site collection administrator account. In these site collections, search is not working. It is giving zero result items with no error in UI and hive logs.

Does having an invalid account as site collection administrator impact the search in those site collections?

Whenever I add myself to site collection administrators from Central Administration, and open the site and start searching, I am seeing zero results with no errors in search results and no errors in SharePoint hive logs. Once I wait until the next incremental crawl happens, then I am able to search properly in that site collection.

So please let me know if having an invalid site collection administrator impacts the SharePoint search?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, at least the documentation doesn't say so, unless the default content access account is reused as a site Collection Admin, why should not be the case, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/best-practices-for-crawling

Answer (score 0):

It seems issue is not related to that site collection administrator expiration ID, Basically search will not refer any user ID to crawl the content but it will see the permission level when the user view the documents,so open any document library from that site collection and go to library settings then advanced settings and there you can find an option called "Reindex Document Library", just click on it and wait till the next crawl and then search the content..